# Accept Payment without leaving site for merchant outside US

Tags: paypal

How can a merchant located outside countries such as the USA and UK where the new PayPal API is available can process credit-card payments with PayPal without having their clients leaving their merchant website?

In other words is there a way to use PayPal as a payment Gateway for merchant outside USA and not use those buy button that look awfully unprofessional.

I actually am in Switzerland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some countries outside of the U.S can use Payflow and hosted checkout pages and they can place the credit card sections within an iFrame so that it does not appear that the merchant is leaving your site.  However these services are not available for every country.  Currently Switzerland is not one that can use Payflow/hosted checkout pages.